# Scraping a Nested Table from TMX.com in R

Tags: html, r, xpath, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape the main table (option chain) from this website https://web.tmxmoney.com/options.php?qm_symbol=SLF&qm_page=19300 From looking at the html/css code it seems like the table is within a table. When I use html_nodes("table") I am returned only the header table. When I try to dive deeper with an xpath I am returned a list with nothing in it. I have also tried using selector gadget but I am still getting a list of length 0. I have tried many different xpaths but will only provide my most recent

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(httr)
url = "https://web.tmxmoney.com/options.php?qm_symbol=SLF&qm_page=19300"
chain = read_html(url)%>%html_nodes(xpath = '//div[@class="qm-container"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table') %>% html_table(fill = T)

{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

Here is the table I am trying to scrape.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with below xpath.

```
 //div[@class="qm-container"]/table/tbody/tr/td//table[@class='qm_heading_bar']
```

Comment: I am still unable to retrieve it. I am getting back a list of length 0.